# My app is Rejected from appstore due to metadata

Tags: ios

My app is rejected from Apple appstore due to metadata. Why did they reject my app?

What I got from Apple:

> 2. 1 Performance: App Completeness Guideline 2.1 - Information Needed
>
> We have started the review of your app, but we are not able to
>   continue because we need additional information about your app.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To help us proceed with the review of your app, please review the
>   following questions and provide as much detailed information as you
>   can.
>
> - Does your app access any paid content or services?
> - What are the paid content or services, and what are the costs?
> - Do individual customers pay for the content or services?
> - If no, does a company or organization pay for the content or services?
> - Where do they pay, and what's the payment method?
> - If users create an account to use your app, are there fees involved?
> - How do users obtain an account?
>
> Once you reply to this message in Resolution Center with the requested
>   information, we can proceed with your review.
>
> Since your App Store Connect status is Metadata Rejected, we do NOT
>   require a new binary. To revise the metadata, visit App Store Connect
>   to select your app and revise the desired metadata values. Once you’ve
>   completed all changes, reply to this message in Resolution Center and
>   we will continue the review.

Comment: Answer their questions and provide them with some test account, so that Apple team could review your app.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Apple send you a list of question. Why not start with that list first? And maybe do a bit of research **how** the whole process works?!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not Apple Developer Support. Reach out to them via resolution center if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

Your app is fine and this is standard apple behaviour. What happening is apple is trying to intimidate you in order to get their share of potential in app payments. It doesn't matter if you charge for your app or not you will receive this apple store reject after a while. Review the app store guidelines and try to answer the questions to best fit into the guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

> reply to this message in Resolution Center

Just answer those questions in Resolution Center would be enough from your end.

> revise the desired metadata values.

Check if there is any changes are required in app store app info section, then make those changes and you are good to go.

After that apple will continue the review.

Answer (score 0):

Just answer the questions they asked.

They asked such question because they must found some payment related things inside your app.

```
- Does your app access any paid content or services?
Ans. No. or if any then write yes. 
- What are the paid content or services, and what are the costs?
Ans. No paid Content. or if any then describe it.
- Do individual customers pay for the content or services?
Ans. No. if any then describe it.
- If no, does a company or organization pay for the content or services?
Ans. Describe how you provide content in app paid or free.
- Where do they pay, and what's the payment method?
Ans. no payment needed. or describe if any like offline.
- If users create an account to use your app, are there fees involved?
Ans. no.
- How do users obtain an account?
Ans. describe the process of registration like offline, using sign up or through website etc.
```

After you are done, resubmit your app.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing at all except that you'll have to provide details regarding Pricing and availability.
Fill out all the details in "Pricing and Availability" page in general tab left hand side menu in Appstore.
If you don't have any pricing services and products. Select USD 0.0 (free) in price schedule option in same page. [Just like in screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqIkx.png) and
[Availability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzHGc.png)